# How much magnesium can a person really consume without side effects?

Tags: magnesium

This is the current "Recommended Daily Allowance of Magnesium" table:

```
Age         Male    Female  Pregnancy

≤6 mo       30 mg   30 mg   …
7-12 mo     75 mg   75 mg   …
1-3 y       80 mg   80 mg   …
4-8 y       130 mg  130 mg  …
9-13 y      240 mg  240 mg  …
14-18 y     410 mg  360 mg  400 mg
19-30 y     400 mg  310 mg  350 mg
31-50 y     420 mg  320 mg  360 mg
≥51 y       420 mg  320 mg  …
```

But that's something approved for the mass public with normal lifestyles and this table assumes no additional factors that drain magnesium (e.g. chronic stress).

Let's assume that due to chronic stress and mental effort a person is symptomatic with magnesium deficiency symptoms like muscle weakness and fatigue and muscle twitches.

So, in such case how much magnesium can a person ***really*** eat daily? Does this make any sense whatsoever to eat for example 600 mg of Mg citrate daily or the body doesn't need more than 420 mg daily regardless of the situation?

Comment: Who says chronic stress depletes magnesium? Please cite a source for that claim.

Comment: Also, I know a _lot_ of people who supplement magnesium from another health-related forum I participate in, and how much people can tolerate before diarrhea occurs depends on the individual and the formulation they take. You'll find almost no one who can tolerate doses higher than shown in that table. But keep in mind the table isn't recommending supplementation at those doses; the table lists recommended amounts from all sources, the majority of which should be diet.

Comment: A 2500 Kcal whole food diet (no refined oils, sugar etc. only whole grains, starches  and fats only from nuts and seeds) will typically yield about 1 gram of magnesium.

Answer (score 1):

Symptomatic magnesium deficiency due to "chronic stress" and "mental effort" in an otherwise healthy person on a regular diet is unlikely.

> Symptomatic magnesium deficiency due to low dietary intake in
>   otherwise-healthy people is uncommon because the kidneys limit urinary
>   excretion of this mineral ([Office of Dietary Supplements,
>   NIH.gov](https://ods.od.nih.gov/factsheets/Magnesium-HealthProfessional/)).

According to the same source, Tolerable Upper Intake Levels (ULs) for supplemental magnesium is 350 mg/day for adults, which is even lower than the Recommended Dietary Allowance, which is 420 mg/day. This is because magnesium from supplements tends to have a **laxative effect** in lower doses than the magnesium from food. The actual Mg dose that can trigger diarrhea can vary greatly from person to person, though.